# how to hide android navigation bar when user touched input?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a  fullscreen flutter app , when i click on textformfield , android navigation bar appears and when i finished typing and closed textformfield , navigation bar still is showing  .
how to solve this problem ? 
this is my code to set flutter app full screen :

```
await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
  [DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
```

Any Suggestion is helpful, thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, it will hide the navigation bar, when your field is submitted.

```
TextFormField(
  onFieldSubmitted: (string){
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  },
);
```

Comment: You can also do that in `onSaved` or setting up a `FocusNode` listener.